# How to show "CA1806: Do not ignore method results" for ImmutableList<T>.Add?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to show a warning when you call `ImmutableList<T>.Add` but don't use its result?

I thought CA1806 would do that, and it does for some methods that return results (like string.ToUpper() from the screenshot), but not for `ImmutableList<T>.Add`.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the help page for [CA1806](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1806#rule-description), the cause of this:

> There are several possible reasons for this warning:
>
> - A new object is created but never used.
> - A method that creates and returns a new string is called and the new string is never used.
> - A COM or P/Invoke method that returns a HRESULT or error code that's never used.
> - A language-integrated query (LINQ) method that returns a result that's never used.

Note that it only says "a method that creates and returns a new string". It is possible that the analyser *only* looks for `string` methods as the default behaviour. It doesn't "know" that `ImmutableList<T>.Add` also returns a new instance that *should* be used.

As is said in the bottom of that page, you can add more methods that trigger CA1806 by adding the method to the `.editorconfig` option `dotnet_code_quality.CA1806.additional_use_results_methods`. This is a `|` separated list of method names.

```
dotnet_code_quality.CA1806.additional_use_results_methods = M:System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableList`1.Add(`0)
```

Notice the unusual syntax for referring to the method. You can see how this format works [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/standard-v6/standard/documentation-comments.md#d42-id-string-format).

Answer (score 2):

Currently, CA1806 doesn't analyze immutable types invocations. However, this is already [under consideration](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/34098) by the .NET team.

You should either wait for https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/34098 to be approved and implemented, or otherwise, if you really need this, you can write your own DiagnosticAnalyzer.